# A weekly schedule generator based on activities duration and available daily time

Tags: windows, time-management, scheduling

I think that the title summarizes everything, but I need an app that:

- Lets me work on a 5 days schedule
- Lets me specify how many hours I can work per day
- Lets me specify when I can not work (ie: lunch hours)
- Lets me input activity name, duration, days of week (specific or just as a number)
- Automatically generates a schedule

I'm on Windows, but a web app is more than acceptable. Possibly free.

Comment: How about google calendar?  Anytime that is does not have an appointment is considered free.  You can block off all evenings and etc with a single recurring event.  You can easily add a recurring lunch and change it as needed.  It looks like a calendar on screen, you can print it, and it syncs with smartphones include apple products.